# Why do other tests in a collection run when I select a single test to run?

Tags: c#, testing, automated-tests, xunit

I have a class containing four tests, this class is part of a collection with a shared database fixture. When I execute a single test in the class from Test Explorer in Visual Studio it passes as expected. However, looking at the state of the database after it runs, it seems that some of the other tests are also attempting to run. SQL profiler confirmed this.

SQL profiler also revealed that the database fixture constructor is being executed multiple times when a single test is selected to run.

The behavior is the same when I execute just the one test by right clicking it in the code editor and selecting run.

I tried removing the class from the collection, and instantiating the database fixture within each of the test methods in the class.

This actually does result in the expected database state after a single test has been run. I just don't understand why removing the tests from the collection results in different behavior. From my understanding, the whole point of a collection fixture is to have it run once for all tests in the collection.

It would be preferable to keep the tests in a single collection, as the database fixture loads some data in it's constructor. It is much slower to instantiate it for every test and requires a fair amount of wiring in each test method.

Simplified example:

```cs
    public class DatabaseFixture : IDisposable
    {
        internal IDbConnection Db;
        internal IConfiguration Configuration;
        internal OrmLiteConnectionFactory dbFactory;

        public DatabaseFixture()
        {
            Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
            var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString(name: "Connection");

            dbFactory
               = new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(connectionString, SqlServerDialect.Provider, false);

            Db = dbFactory.Open();

            Db.ExecuteNonQuery("DELETE FROM TestTable");

        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            
        }
    }
```

```cs
    [CollectionDefinition("TestCollection")]
    public class TestCollection : ICollectionFixture<DatabaseFixture>
    {
    }
```

```cs
    [Collection("TestCollection")]
    public class TestClass
    {
        DatabaseFixture dbFixture;
        public TestClass(DatabaseFixture database)
        {
            dbFixture = database;
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            dbFixture.Db.Insert<TestTable>(new TestTable { Value = DateTime.Now.ToString(), Method = "TEST 1" });
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Test2()
        {
            dbFixture.Db.Insert<TestTable>(new TestTable { Value = DateTime.Now.ToString(), Method = "TEST 2" });

        }
    }
```

Executing only Test1 produces the following in the table:
[image]

Then when I change TestClass to the following:

```cs
    public class TestClass
    {
        DatabaseFixture dbFixture;

        [Fact]
        public void Test1()
        {
            dbFixture = new();
            dbFixture.Db.Insert<TestTable>(new TestTable { Value = DateTime.Now.ToString(), Method = "TEST 1" });
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Test2()
        {
            dbFixture = new();
            dbFixture.Db.Insert<TestTable>(new TestTable { Value = DateTime.Now.ToString(), Method = "TEST 2" });

        }
    }
```

And execute only Test1, I get the expected result:
[image]

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible example of your problem.

Comment: how should we guess about what your test-code does when you don't show the code? The ctor of a fixture may execute multiple times even before any test is executed in order to determine the tests within your fixture (e.g. for TestCaseSource (which is nUnit -  no idea about its counterpart in xUnit)).

Comment: Thanks @MonsieurMerso, I have added an example

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain the fixture ctor running multiple times isn't necessarily the issue, I just added that bit as I thought it might be related or at least helpful in diagnosing the issue. I have added a simplified example showing the behavior I'm experiencing.

Comment: @Jmeijer,  please can you add the way how you launch your tests? What happens when you use `dotnet test --filter...` command?

Comment: @MonsieurMerso I was launching the tests from the Test Explorer in VS by right clicking the desired test and then clicking run.  `dotnet test --filter...` does seem to be running only the test filtered, I get the desired result when launching it that way

Comment: So, I assume that problem is in VS runner configuration :(